# two sidebar for sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar

I have these rst

- main.rst
- source.rst
- source.file1.rst
- source.file2.rst

left side bar for index.html shows main and source

```
  # index.rst 
  Welcome!
  ==========
  .. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 1
  
     main
     source
```

but the left side bar for source.html shows main, source (with file1, file2 nested inside source)

```
  # source.rst 
  Source
  ==========
  .. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 1
  
     source.file1
     source.file2
```

My conf.py

```
  # conf.py
  html_sidebars = {
     '**': [
        'localtoc.html',
        'globaltoc.html'
     ],
  }
```

My problem is that I want to have 2 distinct and independent side bar for index.html and source.html. I've tried playing around with localtoc.html and global.html to no avail.

Comment: Put files into directories. For example, `source/index.rst` and `source/file1.rst`. Then adjust the paths in the files.

Comment: Hi @StevePiercy thank you for your reply. I didn't quite understand what do you mean by this. I tried separating them into folders. But the left sidebar will only obey the index.rst

Comment: When you move the files, you need to adjust the toctree entry paths accordingly.

Comment: Yup, I've tried to move them and update the toctree, and inside the subdirectory, like so: subdir/index.rst. But when i open the subdir/index.html, the sidebar would still be from the root index.html

Comment: I can't make sense of what you did. Please update your question with your file structure and your toctree entries.